# Python: join a list inside a list

Tags: python-3.x, list

Assume I have the following

```
    [['Came',
  'here',
  'for',
  'the',
  'witches',
  ',',
  'stayed',
  'for',
  'the',
  'Gwent',
  '.'],
 ['Great',
  'horror',
  'game',
  ',',
  'can',
  'get',
  'a',
  'little',
  'repetitive',
  'so',
  'a',
  'new',
  'fresh',
  'set',
  'of',
  'maps',
  'is',
  'ideal.The',
  'level',
  'up',
  'system',
  'is',
  'trash',
  ',',
  'i',
  "'ve",
  'never',
  'been',
  'so',
  'confused',
  'between',
  '2',
  'addons',
  ',',
  'offerings',
  ',',
  'and',
  'perk',
  'system.Major',
  'downfall',
  'is',
  'the',
  'match-making',
  'system',
  ',',
  'you',
  'can',
  'be',
  'thrown']]
```

Is it possible to turn it into something like the following

```
[['Came here for the witches, stayed for the Gwent.'], 
["Great horror game, can get a little repetitive so a new fresh set of maps is ideal.The level up system is trash, i've never been so confused between 2 addons, offerings, and perk system.Major downfall is the match-making system, you can be thrown]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the join method and list interpretation

```
new_list = [[" ".join(x)] for x in list]
```